Vscode + MSYS2: print problem in python script
I have installed MSYS2 and Vscode on Windows 10. I have set the bash(MSYS2) as the default terminal in Vscode.
When I run cpp program or python program, the terminal will display extra strings before the program output. Like this.

If I resize the window, these text in red will disappear. This is wired. How to solve it. Thanks.

Did you open a github issue with VSCode already?

No. Is it a Vscode bug or my error settings? I am not sure.

I used to get those from time to time too, never figured it out. My bet is that it's some broken shell integration. There's a setting for it, try disabling it (you'll lose ctrl+up/down shortcuts though).

I got it. And solve it.

It might be a VSCode error, I'd just report it and see. (Help menu, report bug.)

Yes. I also find that it does not appear every time.

I wonder if it is related at all to this: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/211755

Well, I solve it. I carefully check my settings and process. Maybe the VScode cannot handle bash(MSYS2) perfectly.
I also read the official guide agagin Get Started with C++ and MinGW-w64 in Visual Studio Code
In the guide, it told us that we should add C:\msys64\ucrt64\bin into you PATH. Then set the PowerShell as the default terminal.
Then the output of terminal become clean and right.

USE the POWERSHELL as default terminal if you can.
